# How to make all categories into in one array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables namely **categories & stores**. Now I need to fetch data from those tables in array format using php. Where I'm getting the data from those tables in array format. But I need to categories those data base on **category name.**

Here is the tables that I'm using to retrieve data.
[image: Tables]

Here is my php code to fetch data from db.

```
<?php
$sql_query = "SELECT store_id, store_name, store_url, category_id, (SELECT categories_name FROM categories_list WHERE categories_id = stores_list.category_id) AS category_name FROM  `stores_list`  order by category_id asc";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $data["countries_list"][] = array("category_name" => $row['category_name'],
        "stores_list"=>array("store_id" => $row['store_id'], "store_name" => $row['store_name'],"store_url" => $row['store_url']));
 }
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Here is the output I'm getting for the above code.
[image: getting output]

Here is the desired output.
[image: desired output]

Comment: same keys inside array is not possible as in your desired format  `stores_list` have same keys repeatedly. that's actually not possible. the latest value of key will over-write the first value and every-time single key 
 with latest data you will get. Check here:-https://eval.in/926549

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh I have changed the desired output format.

Comment: check the answer below. I think that matched to your desired format

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT store_id, store_name, store_url, category_id, (SELECT categories_name FROM categories_list WHERE categories_id = stores_list.category_id) AS category_name FROM  `stores_list`  order by category_id asc";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $data["countries_list"][$row['category_name']] = array("category_name" => $row['category_name']);
    $data["countries_list"][$row['category_name']]["stores_list"]["stores_info"][] = array("store_id" => $row['store_id'], "store_name" => $row['store_name'],"store_url" => $row['store_url']);
}
$data["countries_list"] = array_values($data["countries_list"]);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: this will not meet OP's desired format, because OP's desired format is not possible at all. Why? For that Check my comment under question

Comment: Yes you are right that's why i make array for stores_list. Which is close to that format.

Comment: @JasminMistry I have modified the output pattern format. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: @JsaminMistry I'm not getting like desired output. Please once go through the desired output format